# ARX Anonymization Tool - supported databases

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, data-masking

We are looking into options for open source data masking tools. ARX seems to provide some great functionality, but only lists SQLServer and DB2 (along with flat files and Excel in it's list). Does anyone know what types of things are supported? Oracle for example? How about old-school things like VSAM?

https://arx.deidentifier.org/anonymization-tool/

Anyone have any other great options for data masking? Hopefully something UI-configured, as it's typically not programmers managing the data.

Answer (score 3):

Many great tools exist to help you anonymize data, and it’s a growing field, given the increasing need for data privacy and the demands of recent regulations. Here are just a few of the leading products for data anonymization; quotations are from product websites.

Open Source

ARX Data Anonymization Tool - https://arx.deidentifier.org/
“ARX features a cross-platform graphical tool, which supports data import and cleansing, wizards for creating transformation rules, intuitive ways for tailoring the anonymized dataset to your requirements and visualizations of data utility and re-identification risks.”

Masquerade - https://github.com/TonicAI/masquerade 
“Masquerade can anonymize data in real-time enabling anonymous analytics, application development, and QA testing with next to no overhead. It does this by operating a TCP proxy between your Postgres client and Postgres database and modifying the result-sets generated by SELECT statements according to a set of user-defined rules.”

Amnesia - https://amnesia.openaire.eu/
“Amnesia is a data anonymization tool, that allows to remove identifying information from data. Amnesia not only removes direct identifiers like names, SSNs etc but also transforms secondary identifiers like birth date and zip code so that individuals cannot be identified in the data. Amnesia supports k-anonymity and km-anonymity.”

SaaS / Enterprise

Tonic (Synthetic Data Generator) - https://www.tonic.ai/
“Tonic uses pre-trained models and feature extraction to generate synthetic data that is based on your data. It preserves all the characteristics that make your data unique—constraints, statistical correlations, distributions, interdependencies, etc. Mask, anonymize, obscure, or generate brand new data, all at the click of a mouse.”

Informatica (Dynamic or Persistent Data Masking Products) - https://www.informatica.com/in/products/data-security/data-masking.html#fbid=3YKt13oZ5As
“De-identify, de-sensitize, and anonymize sensitive data from unauthorized access for application users, business intelligence, application testing, and outsourcing.”

Oracle (Data Masking and Subsetting Pack) - https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/security/data-masking-subsetting.html
“Oracle Data Masking and Subsetting helps database customers improve security, accelerate compliance, and reduce IT costs by sanitizing copies of production data for testing, development, and other activities and by easily discarding unnecessary data.”

This list could be much longer; the above is just a sampling. Other companies that offer data masking products include Delphix, IBM, Microsoft SQL Server, Aircloak.

Full disclosure: I'm a founder of Tonic.

Comment: Thank you for the great insight into options. We've already looked at some of them and we'll take a peek at some others you have listed. We were more curious specifically about ARX and if it handled Oracle database. Are you aware?

Answer (score 0):

ARX developer here. When using the Java library you can connect to any database with a JDBC driver. We also support connections to Oracle via the GUI. AFAICT some users have reported problems when connecting to Oracle databases, though. You have to check.